# Looking for Shadow Robot stack for Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would love to know if there is an ETA or at least a promise of a release for the Shadow Robot stack specifically looking for the cyberglove package that is compatible with Fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33231/looking-for-shadow-robot-stack-for-fuerte/) by [Sir Penguins](https://answers.ros.org/users/2310/sir-penguins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I now released the cyberglove package for Fuerte. It has been moved to a different stack called sr_teleop.

You can install it:

```
> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-sr-teleop
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0